# Structuring JSON schema with hierarchical definitions

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm new in writing JSON schemas. I thought I could use the following structure in my schema file. What do you think, is this feasible?

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "my_object": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/my_object"
        }
    },
    "formats": {
        "language": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$"
        },
        "zipcode": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "\\d{5}-\\d{4}|\\d{5}"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "my_object": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "language": {"$ref": "#/formats/language"},
                "zipcode": {"$ref": "#/formats/zipcode"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The top level only contains references to objects under `definition`. Since I need some type & pattern pairs more than once I put them under `formats`.

Is `definitions` a key word in JSON schema? At least it is widely used in examples. Is it ok to add your own "key words" like `formats` here or should everything go under `definitions`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a lot of examples indeed use `definitions` it is outdated and the recommended way is to use `$defs` instead. Other keys are still supported to be backwards compatible. [See here for more](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/512#issuecomment-353403603)

Thus, I'd recommend keeping all sub-schemas in the `$defs` object. It is still possible to to group semantically related sub-schemas inside `$defs` so if you insist on keeping the the distinction you can do something like this:

```json
{
   "properties":{
      "my_object":{
         "$ref":"#/$defs/my_object"
      }
   },
   "$defs":{
      "my_object":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "language":{
               "$ref":"#/$defs/formats/language"
            },
            "zipcode":{
               "$ref":"#/$defs/formats/zipcode"
            }
         }
      },
      "formats":{
         "language":{
            "type":"string",
            "pattern":"^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$"
         },
         "zipcode":{
            "type":"string",
            "pattern":"\\d{5}-\\d{4}|\\d{5}"
         }
      }
   }
}
```